# How do I set default variables for bound forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

I tried:

```
form = JournalForm(initial={'tank': 123})
```

but as the documentation says, it does not work for bound forms. What can I do to populate the input fields with default values in bound forms ? The values are supposed to be variable as well.

I my case I want to create a form that allows users to change their email address. The current email address is supposed to be in the input field.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to not use a modelform ? Also, I'm not sure you understand bound forms correctly, can you detail the chronology of events that bothers you when using initial ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. The purpose of `initial` is to set the initial data for the form. Do you have somethng similar to this? Note that you do not need to specify the initial data if the form was posted, because the values are in the POST data already:

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JournalForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = JournalForm(initial={'tank': 123})

    return render_to_response(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not check whether request.POST existed. It was probably bad coding, but it never raised any errors.